# How to delete non-relevant warning in TS

Tags: typescript

I have a program I to collage in TS and I'm not allowed to submit it if it has warnings (red underlines). I don't know how to get rid of my red underline:
In the code, I get to a place that I know that `exp.exps[0]` is of type `A` which has a propery `num`, but VSC doesn't know that my object `x` is of type `A` and underlines `x.num`: (`x` is a map).

```
export const foo = (x: SuperTypeOfA): number => {
if (isOfTypeA(x)) return x.num;
return -1;}

interface A {tag: "A"; num: number; };
const isOfTypeA= (x: any): x is A=> x.tag === "A";

type SuperTypeOfA = A | B | C | D | E;
```

Comment: How dows your `isOfTypeA` function look?

Comment: That doesn't look like valid syntax - is `foo` meant to be an object or a function?

Comment: @sefe I'll add it.

Comment: @JoeClay `foo` is a function.

Comment: Have you tried to define your type guard in function syntax (`function isOfTypeA(x: any): x is A { return x.tag === "A"; }`)? The logic seems correct but it is odd that you define your function as `const`.

Comment: @Sefe Thanks, that isn't the main pont here.

Comment: It might actually be the main point. I'm using type guards all the time and they always work. The only difference I see is the syntax.

Comment: @J.Doe please can you update your code to a minimal but fully working example of your problem. Types `B`, `C`, `D`, `E` are missing and when I place the code inside of the TypeScript playground, I get no error on the line you describe.

Comment: @J.Doe I had too many types so the problem was that I didn't approach a propriate field of the map.